# React-Redux: How to update props of component whenever they change?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My header component is not not receiving new props until I manually re-render the entire page. And i wonder why?

Basiclly i have four conditions to render my header: idle, loading, success, failure.

1. In idle the user sees the LoggedOutNavbar
2. In loading the user sees the LoadingNavbar
3. In success the user sees the LoadedNavbar
4. In failure the user sees the LoggedOutNavbar

When the user accesses the login page for the first time, the status is idle. If he then clicks the login button, the login is successful, but the header does not receive the new load and success status as props. So the header remains the same like in the logged out state. However, when the page is manually reloaded and the actions are dispatched again, the new props are available and the new header is displayed. I wonder how I can get the same result without manually reloading the page?

```
export class Header extends Component {

   componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProfile();
    this.props.loadUser();
  }
    
    render() {

        const {profile} = this.props.profile;
        const isFetching = this.props.isFetching
        const {isAuthenticated} = this.props.auth

        if (isFetching === "idle") return (<LoggedOutNavbar />)

        if (isFetching === "loading" ) return (<Fragment> <LoadingNavbar /> </Fragment> )

        if (isFetching === "success") return (<LoadedNavbar profile = {profile[0]} isAuthenticated ={isAuthenticated}/>)

        if (isFetching === "failure") return (<LoggedOutNavbar />)


  
}
}


function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const auth = state.auth
    const profile = state.profile
    const isFetching = state.profile.isFetching

  return { auth, profile, isFetching}
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getProfile, loadUser }
)(Header);
```

```
header.js:34 idle    // Logged Out state
header.js:34 loading  
header.js:34 success  // Logged in state, after manually rerendering
header.js:34 success // Logged in state, after manually rerendering
header.js:34 idle  // Logged Out state
header.js:34 idle  // Logged in state but header is still in idle
header.js:34 idle  // Logged in state but header is still in idle
```

**EDIT:**
When inspecting my Redux Dev Tools, i see that the Profile is is actually not changing from idle to another state. I aussme the getProfile function is not called again after the login.

Comment: Can you confirm that the state has changed via viewing the state in the Redux devtools?

Comment: @Wezelkrozum you are right. In the Redux-Devtool there is no change of the status displayed. It remains in idle. I suppose this is because the function `getprofile` in `ComponentDidMount` is called only once when the component is loaded, but not a second time after login.

Comment: @dan_boy It's probably simpler to make Header a functional component with an [effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). If you see the class example of the documentation then you see that you need to implement `componentDidUpdate` as well to see if some prop changed. You can also set the needed redux state values when you log in and then the mapStateToProps should load the changed values (unless you mutate state in your reducer).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, `componentDidMount` is called only once before the component renders initially. However, to register a change in the component, `componentDidUpdate` is required. Whenever the user has changed the state of `isAuthenticated`, the component calls the `getProfile` action and renders the component again.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
// Update profile after user loggs out or loggs in:
if (this.props.isAuthenticated !== prevProps.isAuthenticated) {
  this.props.getProfile();
}
}
```